# ajax loading result cannot set cookie

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies, droppable

I use ajax to do mysql search in php then loading image in div.
If draggable to droppable area will set cookie, but show error! (Isn't droppable)

```
$( "#droppable_area" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {           
        A.push(ui.draggable.find("img").attr("id"));
        B.push("1");
        $.cookie('tempA', A);
        $.cookie('tempB', B);
    }
})
```

If remove `$.cookie('tempA', A);` and `$.cookie('tempB', B);` will can do it(droppable).
I have loaded cookie.js.

Please tell me why, thank you!

Comment: But, the title have not relation with your question